# Error Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android

I received when execute a new Android Studio project:  Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

```html
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.davidontalba.app2"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
}
```

Help! I cant do someone proyect in Android Studio and i dont understand why...

Comment: current version of support lib is 23.4.0, but you need to show the layout file that caused the problem, or error stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your classpath in your projects's build.gradle to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'`. Use **gradle 1.5 or greater** preferably `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0`.  That fixed mine.

Comment: 1.5 go perfect, but greater of that, tell me that: Warning:Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.4. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in \\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip

Comment: but, this url doesn´t exist in my pc

Comment: to use gradle greater than 1.5, go to File > project structure > project ( or you can just press ctrl +alt + shift + S then select project)  then change gradle version to 2.10.  Also go to File > settings > Build,execution,deployment >Build tools > gradle  then select use default gradle wrapper